# Area 51 Statistics

Tags: discussion

[image]

Let's go through this from best to worst:

1. **100% answered - excellent**: Need I say more? We've answered every question.
2. Around **4.2 answers a question - excellent**. So we're kind of rocking the answers.
3. **48 avid users, 1,255 total users - okay** (on pace for 80 200+ rep users, 3 2000+, and 3 3000+). So, we're not bad here - but we could use more users. We've posted ads on other sites, have a twitter account, and people are emailing those they know to spread the word. Plus, it's summer, so this number will likely get a boost come September. It's important, of course, to encourage people who come to *stay*, and I think this community is very welcoming, so that shouldn't be a big problem =)
4. **1,177 visits per day - okay** - this got a big boost since the last time I checked it. We're not that far from the "good" mark! I think it helps that we've gotten quite a few hot network questions (HNQs) recently - so upvote good questions when you see them!
5. **4 questions per day - needs work** - okay, so we've got a bit to go on this one. We should get around 6 more questions a day. So first, I'd encourage the current regulars to ask questions when you've got them - but also, this will increase as more users join and site views increase.

We're thirty days in. I think we can reach all of these goals at ninety days. What do you all think?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with looking at the Area 51 numbers occasionally, but the Community Managers (Stack Exchange employees responsible for growing and overseeing the individual sites), including me, consider them more or less obsolete as metrics of how communities are doing. For a (somewhat) more recent view of our thinking, see [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites).

Answer (score 3):

I've done some (very basic) comparsion of 15 beta sites using [this data dump](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/161/2) to find out how good our statistics are compared to the ones of other sites.

- **Number of questions per day:** We're above the average amount and in the top 3 sites. No site in the dump reaches the "Excellent" threshold though.
  The number of questions per day still needs work. As [Robert Cartaino](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/robert-cartaino) has stated in [their answer](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/64) to a question about the chances of success for this site, it's important to note that

  > [...] having the same people ask more questions is not sustainable and not a solution [...]

  As he continues, he points out that we should focus on getting more users to increase the number of questions per day.
- **Percentage answered:** Everything fine, excellent work!
- **Avid users:** Only at about ${1}\over{3}$ of the "Excellent" threshold, you might interpret the data as a slight increase over time in beta, but I'm not sure.
- **Total users:** About $0.6$ times of the average user count (I think this is good nevertheless as we managed to get those users quite quickly).
- **Answer ratio:** In my view, our answer ratio is absolutely awesome ;) - the only ratio rated "Excellent" in the dump by the way. Even if the ratio drops by $1.8$ questions, it would still be "Excellent".
- **Visits per day:** Compared to time, this is also amazing, I think. We are one out of three sites rated "Okay" and approaching "Excellent", the other two sites rated "Okay" have been in beta for around 200 and 400 days.

I think that in the following month (when this site continues to be established), the visits per day will increase. I think it's likely that the amount of visits per day will be "Excellent" by the end of the 90 day period.

Concerning users and therefore the number questions per day, I'm also waiting for [the end of summer](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/summer-is-coming) to see both numbers increasing.

Due to our high answer ratio, we have also often made questions get it into the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), which are displayed on a sidebar on most sites of the Stack Exchange network. This, of course, helps us to gain more attention and is therefore a good way to get more users.

---

**Further updates and observations**

- 2017-06-24: Visits per day are around 1,800 and rated "Excellent" now. Faster than I expected.

Comment: Nice analysis, thank you!

Comment: Moving along rather nicely. :)

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Yes, definitely :) I wondered whether I'd include something like this as a TL;DR...

Answer (score 2):

I'm planning to do a basic comparison of some Area 51 statistics, so I've put the information of the first 15 sites in public beta into a small spreadsheet.

As asked in chat, I'll provide the data as a CSV dump in a community wiki answer here. Feel free to edit in more sites or updated statistics.

*Disclaimer: I've tried my best to edit all the information exactly, but it's of course possible that I've made mistakes or typos (so there's no warranty assumed here). Additionally, all information is subject to rapid change.*

```
Site,Days in beta,Questions per day,Answered,Avid users,Total users,Answer ratio,Visits/day
Bioinformatics,38,5.9,95%,49,957,2.1,281
Computer Sciene Educators,31,3.9,99%,51,"1,291",4.2,"1,177"
DevOps,115,3.1,84%,62,"2,248",1.9,386
Vegetarianism,143,0.1,98%,64,775,1.9,57
Korean Language,367,1,99%,65,971,1.8,299
Ukrainian Language,136,0.6,92%,66,"1,026",1.8,186
Artifical Intelligence,325,1.7,82%,70,"6,921",2,287
Arts and Crafts,423,0.9,95%,74,"2,162",1.9,844
Internet of Things,199,2.1,93%,83,"3,135",1.8,602
Language learning,444,0.8,91%,89,"2,448",1.9,77
Esperanto Language,304,0.4,100%,117,942,2.4,88
Literature,156,3.3,74%,126,"1,678",1.4,452
Monero,339,2.3,95%,172,"1,689",1.5,"2,432"
Sitecore,283,7.2,90%,174,"1,991",1.7,"2,042"
Retrocomputing,430,1.4,94%,189,"3,172",2.2,445
```